# Find the limit function for the sequence of function problem

Tags: sequence-of-function

Let us consider the sequence of function $$
f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
nx, x\in [0, 1/2^n] \\
1/nx, x \in (1/2^n, 1]\\
\end{cases}
$$
Find the limit function $f(x).$

My work:

if $x \in [0, 1/2^n]$ then $f_n(x)$ goes to zero for sufficiently large $n.$ For $x = 1,$ $f_n(x)$ tends to $0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty.$ Now for $1/2^n<x<1,$ keep $x$ fixed. Then $1/2^n < x$ for sufficiently large $n.$ Now what can I conclude about the limit function $f(x)?$

Answer (score 1):

You know that $1/2^n \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0$ so for all $\epsilon>0$, it exists a rank $N$ so that $1/2^n<\epsilon$ then $f_n$ tends to be $x \mapsto 1/nx$ which converges to $0$.